# Closing as off topic should be more consistent, close others in same boat

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, moderation

I don't understand how my question, [Animated Gifs on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115258/animated-gifs-on-facebook), was closed inside a minute as off topic while other questions in the very same vein remain open.

In the comments I have clearly pointed out other users asking similar questions to mine - these users collecting juicy answers while mine was snipped, closed instantly.

I put forth to the jury that the close decision on my question was incorrect. While I understand the cause of it, I do not understand why others are allowed to post about this subject while I can't.

If the reason is that the other users' questions should have been deleted too, then I would request that they are deleted immediately, post haste.

But that would be a shame considering that they are first hit on a Google search for those terms. But rules are rules, correct?

The moderation process is arbitrary and without oversight. I suggest a process where regular users can put a mod decision into review by other mods if so desired.

EDIT: I posted the original question over at Stack Exchange, let's see well I will be approached: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20825/how-to-post-animated-gifs-on-facebook

EDIT 2: User "phwd" made the rather dumb mistake to close my question over at Stack Exchange without properly reading that I stated that there have been solutions posted already but they are out of date and therefore I have opened up a question about this again. If there are any mods around, please reopen that question.

Comment: I would say that the examples you link to should also have been closed.

Comment: You are (presumably) being downvoted by normal users, not mods.  (although only developers can check that)

Comment: Excellent. Would you mind if I send you a stylesheet of questions that are not completely programming related that should be closed too? It should be quite easy to collect. I presume it will be positive to close this to make SO more what it should be, although it will most likely kill a lot of SEO traffic.

Comment: @SLaks how do you make that presumption? Wild guess?

Comment: There are many more non-mods than mods on StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh you mean that there are many non-mods hanging around on the meta section of StackOverflow?

Comment: @user1005204 Don't send lists of questions that should be closed. Just become a good active member on SO and earn the privilege to vote for closure. And I think you should already be able to flag.

Comment: @SLaks I find myself disagreeing with you again SLaks. Here is my reason. Because this question is related to moderation (as the subject states), and noting that we are on the meta section where there should be a higher percentage of mods/staff than non-mods in comparison to stackoverflow main site, it would not be absurd to claim that some, if not all, down-votes was by members with moderation privileges. Also, I love "random"'s edit of my question here :)

Comment: @user1005204 Well, one of the downvotes was by me, and I'm not a mod, so there you go

Comment: @Michael How cliche. This only proves that you are a minority regardless.

Comment: I down-voted, and flagged your duplicate. SLaks beat me to voting to close the original.

Comment: @Bart: Actually, for flagging one needs at least 15 rep.

Comment: To the meat of it, a lot of people don't like when moderators are attacked so @random 's edit saved you from a flood of down votes. But I agree with you, a lot of people here are missing the point. Slaks did a binding moderator vote, thought the other questions were off topic which *are exact duplicates* of the current one being discussed. Maybe he left to do something else (outside of the Matrix) like cook or walk the dogs before addressing it.

Comment: @OffBySome No clearly you are lying because I corrected you on your answer on this very question and you are paying back the favor by trolling :)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann You are of course correct, I should have mentioned it. That should however not be too difficult to achieve for the OP with some effort.

Comment: "The moderation process is arbitrary and without oversight" Aren't moderators the oversight...?

Comment: @phwd why in the world have you not reopened my question over stack exchange yet? That other question contains answers that are out of date and do not work. If you ask me, your moderation decision is very questionable.

Comment: I added a bounty to the original question http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/how-do-i-post-animated-gifs-on-facebook with a notice that the current answers do not work. Please do not point fingers *especially when people (i.e. myself who up voted this question) are trying to help you*.

Comment: @phwd excellent, how can I assist in this? How can I share my findings to prove that those solutions posted on that other question does not work?

Comment: Nothing else is needed. The notice at the top of post describes that all answers posted so far do not work. There are a few active users on the Facebook tag, someone will come along and grab the bounty by answering the question. You *can* add the question to your favorites by clicking the star and be notified when it is updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The moderation process is arbitrary and without oversight. I suggest a
>   process where regular users can put a mod decision into review by
>   other mods if so desired.

Moderators do their work to the best of their ability and, in my opinion, in this case your question was closed for the right reason. You might feel that it was wrongfully closed, but keep in mind that other "bad" questions not getting caught does not imply that your question should  not be closed either.

Keep in mind that tools with a somewhat similar effect to the review process you suggest are already in place. A productive approach to this situation would be for you to see if you can adapt your question into one which would be a good fit for SO. If not (which I think is the case in this particular situation), take it as it is and let that be it. If you can however, then update your question and vote for it to be reopened. With enough community support you might still get a second chance.

Comment: Good reply Bart. I will approve of its message although I will still await further replies from moderators of stackoverflow.

Comment: I think that if Slaks closed the other questions after being notified from user1005204 about the duplicates (which are clear as day duplicates... maybe it was a long day for Slaks or he was at the beach...) this issue would not have even reached meta. Just my opinion.

Comment: @phwd that is not your opinion, that is what that would have happened. As I stated, I opened this question to seek an answer in why essentially there were other questions with the same subject online while mines was closed.

Answer (score 5):

> While I understand the cause of it, I do not understand why others are allowed to post about this subject while I can't.

Simple: no one person sits and reviews every single question posted on Stack Overflow. Just watch - now that you've linked to other off-topic questions, they're being closed as well, as the moderators and experienced users find them.

If you encounter a problem writing an app for Facebook, or are calling the Facebook API, SO is a perfectly good place to ask your question. But if you're just *using* Facebook, you'll want to go somewhere else.

[Why not try a Q&A site built specifically for questions on web applications like Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/how-do-i-post-animated-gifs-on-facebook)

Comment: My question here was NOT related specifically to using Facebook or related. It was regarding moderation over at Stackoverflow. While I appreciate the content of your reply, I do not see it entirely related to my question. Also, if you did review my initial question, you will see that the solution posted in that link you provided does NOT work... as I claimed already. Nonetheless...

Comment: @user: I responded to your question regarding moderation in my first paragraph. I don't really think you want me to go through your rant and respond to it line-by-line.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115258/animated-gifs-on-facebook) at all, as I can't see the [page behind your link](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=289489697750142) (it says "Dieser Inhalt ist derzeit nicht verfügbar" for me, i.e. *this content is now not available*). If a question relies on outside sources to be understood, it is bad.

- If the question is "How can I post animated GIFs on Facebook?", it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.
- If it is "How can I write a program which creates an animated GIF?", it is simply a too broad question (and should be closed because of this), and I can't see how it relates to Facebook.
- If it is something else, please edit your question to make clear what it actually is. Make sure to include all relevant information in your question.

**Disclaimer:** *I'm not a Stack Overflow moderator, but a [regular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600500/paulo-ebermann). I'm a moderator on [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), though, so I've a bit of experience in moderating.*

Comment: Respectfully, if you cannot view the question at hand, then how in the world did you reply to this question by answering it? You should have stated all of this as a comment and I would have taken actions accordingly. I hope you do not take any offense by what I am tell you here. Just thought I would make it clear what that should be an "Answer" VS "Comment".

Comment: I meant to write that I can't see the facebook page you linked from your SO question. Sorry if this was worded wrongly.

Comment: The reason why you saw that error message was because you were not logged into Facebook when you clicked the link.

Comment: This might be (I have no facebook account). So edit your question to include the necessary information to be understood ... only then one can really judge if your question might be on-topic here.

Comment: I thought that it would be common knowledge to understand that you will need to have a FB account in order to user pictures. Very well - I have updated the original question.

Comment: Your question still doesn't include a question ... it just says: "Look there, how can I do the same?"  Even if the question hidden there wouldn't be off-topic, it is hidden, and should be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Incidentially, the [image](http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/29301_442976909814_310716489814_5773694_3162803_s.jpg) linked at the [similar question on webapps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/how-do-i-post-animated-gifs-on-facebook) can be seen here without logging in.

Comment: Yes, that is because it is a direct link to an image. Apparently, Facebook allows that if it is within a fan page, but it does not allow Guest view of most page unless the privacy settings are set accordingly (which they very rarely are) on personal profiles...

Answer (score 1):

I can't add an answer to your [off-topic and closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115258/animated-gifs-on-facebook), or the [duplicate you posted that got deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115316/animated-gifs-on-facebook).  However, Facebook is notorious for being very anti-animated gifs.  Someone obviously found a loophole, and Facebook I'm sure will close that loop hole very fast.  Don't bother wasting your time trying to spam Facebook with animated gifs, as it won't be an option for long.

And for your meta question here, those previous questions were from a time before Facebook and Stack Overflow launched their facebook.stackoverflow.com partnership, making it the official place to ask Facebook development questions, so there were a lot less people looking at those questions, and thus voting to close them.

Comment: The reason why you cannot answer it there is because it is closed my friend. Please read this thread thorough. Regardless, nothing that you stated there are news to me. I should note though that it is not correct at all. The animated gif scenario have existed for around two years now... unfortunately whom ever who knows how to post them have kept it a secret as I do not see many users doing it.

Comment: Sure, I hope you were not sarcastic there as I did not receive a rep :P